# Почему API возвращает 405:Not Allowed?

Tags: php

Коллеги, доброго времени суток

Пытаюсь использовать API:
https://developer.bitaps.com/forwarding

Подаю POST запрос:

```
    $url = 'https://api.bitaps.com/btc/v1/create/payment/address '; // url, на который отправляется запрос
$post_data = array(
    "forwarding_address"=>"bc1qhlknxc3yqu6z6qy64aascvn23tc8zapc46ynag",
    "callback_link"=>"https://testshopbot.ru/recieve.php",
    "confirmations"=>1
);
$headers =  array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'); // заголовки запроса
$post_data=json_encode($post_data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // true - означает, что отправляется POST запрос
$result = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($result);
```

но возвращает всегда одну ошибку 405:Method not Allowed
Кто подскажет почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $url = 'https://api.bitaps.com/btc/v1/create/payment/address'; // url, на который отправляется запрос
$post_data = array(
    "forwarding_address"=>"bc1qhlknxc3yqu6z6qy64aascvn23tc8zapc46ynag",
    "callback_link"=>"https://testshopbot.ru/recieve.php",
    "confirmations"=>1
);
$headers =  array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'); // заголовки запроса
$post_data=json_encode($post_data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // true - означает, что отправляется POST запрос
$result = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($result);
```

Попробуйте так сделать запрос, простно в конде url был пробел